# How to downgrade Postgres from 9.6 to 9.5

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I removed my 9.6 postgres.app (removing the application by dragging it to the trash) and downloaded postgres.app.

However, when I did

```
locate initdb
```

It still points to the wrong location:

```
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/bin/initdb
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/share/doc/postgresql/html/app-initdb.html
/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.6/share/man/man1/initdb.1
```

What would be the most efficient way to resolve this problem?

Comment: add how you "removed your 9.6"

Comment: since the locate database is updated only on a daily basis you would need to do an `updatedb` before locate points you to the new file

Comment: @e4c5 I installed Posgres by downloading Postgres.app to my mac. It seems like your suggestion is only suitabe for linux?

Comment: updatedb has nothing to do with postgres. It updates the file location database used by locate

Comment: @e4c5 got it! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per e4c5's suggestion, I was able to update the path by doing the following in my OSX environment:

```
sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb
```